# Android Studio gradle build with Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin

When gradle is building, it keeps giving this error

```
"Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Error: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptException: Failed to crunch file C:\Users\KAYODE OGUNSANYA\Desktop\source\and-nd-firebase-1.00-starting-point\and-nd-firebase-1.00-starting-point\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\24.2.0\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_ic_menu_share_mtrl_alpha.png into C:\Users\KAYODE OGUNSANYA\Desktop\source\and-nd-firebase-1.00-starting-point\and-nd-firebase-1.00-starting-point\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_ic_menu_share_mtrl_alpha.png"
```

And this.

```
"Error:com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptException: Failed to crunch file C:\Users\KAYODE OGUNSANYA\Desktop\source\and-nd-firebase-1.00-starting-point\and-nd-firebase-1.00-starting-point\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\24.2.0\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_ic_menu_share_mtrl_alpha.png into C:\Users\KAYODE OGUNSANYA\Desktop\source\and-nd-firebase-1.00-starting-point\and-nd-firebase-1.00-starting-point\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_ic_menu_share_mtrl_alpha.png".
```

Suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean your Project: *Build > Clean Project* and then try again

Answer (score 0):

Change name of your project for example 'firebaseStarting' and clean your Project. Build > Clean Project, I think it will works well